# Matrix Multiplication Using MPI (in C) code isn't working more than 6 nodes

Tags: c, matrix, mpi, multiplication

I'm trying to write a C Program with MPI, The Master Process Makes two 2D Array.

The rows of first Matrix(called A) are distributed to all slave nodes (Using MPI_Scatter) and second matrix(called B) are duplicated to all slave nodes (Using MPI_Bcast).

Rows of Matrix A are duplicated into the other One Dimension Array and multiply Rows of A and Matrix B. The Result of Multiplication are Gathered in Third 2D array (called C) using MPI_Gather.

It works fine when I input 4 or 5 nodes and 4*4 or 5*5 size of array.
For example, It works fine when I input the command like

```
$mpiexec -n 5 -f machinefile ./mpi_test3 5
```

(-> Meaning of second 5 is the size of array. It means multiplication of two 5*5 matrix.)

But it didn't work when i input more than 6 nodes and 6*6 size.
For example,

```
$mpiexec -n 6 -f machinefile ./mpi_test3 6
```

My code Like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <time.h>
     int main(int argc, char* argv[])
     {
       int i, j, k,m, ran, size, myrank, nprocs;
       int a[size][size], b[size][size], c[size][size],ar[size],cr[size];
       ran=10;
       size= atoi(argv[1]);
       MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
       MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);
       MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
    //Initialization of Receive Buffer
       for(i=0;i<size;++i){
            cr[i]=0;
       }
    // make random values and put it into the two Matrix
    if(myrank==0){
         srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
         for(i=0; i<size; ++i)
         {
              for(j=0; j<size; ++j)
              {
                     a[i][j]= rand()%ran+1;
                     b[i][j]= rand()%ran+1;
              }
         }

     }
    //MPI SCATTER & BROAD CAST
    MPI_Scatter(a,size,MPI_INT,&ar,size,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(b,size*size,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
            for(j=0;j<size;++j)
            {
                    cr[i]+=ar[j]*b[j][i];
            }
    }
    MPI_Gather(cr,size,MPI_INT,c,size,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    //Print the Result of Multiplication
   if(myrank==0){
     printf("\t Result of Multiplication \n");
     for(i=0; i<size; ++i){
            for(j=0; j<size; ++j)
            {
                    printf("%d  ",c[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
     }
}

    MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

And my machineFile like this.

```
clus15:2
clus16:2
clus17:2
clus18:2
```

What's the problem of my codes?

Comment: i guess you have to set the `size` value (`size= atoi(argv[1]);`) before defining the size of arrays.

Comment: Thanks, It works fine!! 
It's just simple mistake but i didn't find before..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size needs to be defined before you define your arrays.

```
 int a[size][size], b[size][size], c[size][size],ar[size],cr[size];
```

At that point, size is an undefined variable, and those array are allocated on the stack, before the function enters.

```
int a[atoi(argv[1])][atoi(argv[1])]...,cr[atoi(argv[1])];
```

Also, know that not all compilers support initializing an array with variable size in a function.

Or, alternatively, you could dynamically allocated those arrays, in the following manner:

```
int **a, **b, **c, **ar, *cr;
/* Be sure to check return value of malloc after each call */
a = malloc(sizeof(*a)*size);
b = malloc(sizeof(*b)*size);  
c = malloc(sizeof(*c)*size);
ar = malloc(sizeof(*ar)*size);
cr = malloc(sizeof(*cr)*size);
/* Be sure to check return value of malloc after each call */
for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
     a[i] = malloc(sizeof(**a)*size)
     b[i] = malloc(sizeof(**b)*size)
     c[i] = malloc(sizeof(**c)*size)
     ar[i] = malloc(sizeof(**ar)*size)
```

Currently you are in the realm of undefined behavior, since the arrays are not actually initialized with the size you want, but with non deterministic value that resides in size prior to it's initialization.

Try

```
printf("Size of cr: %d\n", (sizeof(cr)/sizeof(cr[0]));
```

In the main function and see if the array size is equals to the argument you've inputted.